# Moving cursor with the arrow keys in vim normal mode inserts ABCD characters

Tags: vim

As the title says, using the arrow keys puts me in insert mode and adds the A,B,C or D character when I use the arrow keys.

Yes, I got `set nocompatible` in my `.vimrc`
Tried setting `set t_ku=^[OA`, didn't work.
Tried disabling arrow keys in normal mode, didn't work.

I've got ubuntu 16.04 and vim 7.4

Any ideas how I could fix the issue?

Comment: Yeah I use hjlk in most cases. Can't even give an example on when I actually use the arrow keys. But sometime my muscle memory does it automatically i presume and that gives me annoying compilations errors with random "A"s in my code.

Comment: yeah totally :S Have you tried just `mv .vimrc vimrc.bak` etc to see if the problem is in there? Or reinstalling it?

Comment: Starting vim without my .vimrc seems to solve to problem.